# How to disable colorbar in yhat's python ggplot?

Tags: python, python-ggplot

How does one disable colorbar in a plot like so:

```
ggplot(
    aes(x='X',
        y='Y',
        color='C'),
    data=data_df
) + geom_line() + facet_grid("U", "V")
```

The problem is that `C` is of a large cardinality and the point of the plot is just to see the various shapes altogether and not to label them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no direct answer, but after checking the github I don't think it is implemented yet. I would advise you to use `plotnine`, which is also a ggplot wrapper for mpl - but still under development.

E.g.:

```
from plotnine import *
from plotnine import data
(ggplot(data.mtcars, aes('wt', 'mpg', color='factor(gear)'))
 + geom_point(show_legend = False))
```

Comment: plotnine totally did it for me!